# alloca() in caller's space

Tags: c, theory, callstack

Thinking about returning dynamic or automatic arrays. Not really C-related.

The usual technique to return an array is: A) callee allocates on heap and returns, B) caller allocates on stack and passes to callee.

```
// A
void caller(void) {
    int *a = callee();
    free(a);
}
int *callee(void) {
    int *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(*a));
    return a;
}

// B
void caller(void) {
    int a[10]; callee(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
}
void callee(int *a, size_t n) {
    //
}
```

Case A may lead to unnecessary allocate-free cycle, while case B requires syntactic garbage in caller. In B we also can't compute `n` in callee, because it comes predefined. We also can't return automatic storage because it will be destroyed on return (accessing it is UB in general).

But what if we introduce new `return_auto` operator that will return from callee, but leave it's stack frame intact, as if caller did all the job on it's own stack?

```
// C
void caller(void) {
    int *a = callee();
}
int *callee() {
    int a[compute_n()];
    return_auto a;
}
```

I mean, caller could inherit callee's stack frame and all issues disappear. It's stack frame would look like this after return_auto:

```
[caller frame]
  arguments
  ret-pointer
  locals
    int *a = callee.a

  [callee frame] (defunct)
    arguments
    ret-pointer
    locals
      int a[n] (still alive)
  [end-of-callee-frame]

[end-of-caller-frame]
```

In machine code (x86 at least) this may be implemented by jumping to ret-pointer at `ss:ebp` instead of `mov esp, ebp / ret n`. We already have VLAs in modern C, and this looks very similar but slightly complex.

Of course that should be used with care, because series of return_auto's would leave pretty huge dump on stack, that will be "collected" only when outermost caller returns (normally). But stack allocations are insanely cheap, and in theory some algorithms could benefit from not calling malloc/free at all. This is also interesting in code structuring perspective, not just performance.

Does anyone know where this technique is implemented / stack frames joined?
(C is just an example here)

---

Okay, it needs a simple example.

```
void caller(Context *ct) {
    char *s = make_s(ct);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

void make_s(Context *ct) {
    const char *tag = "?", *name = "*";

    if (ct->use_tag) tag = ct->tag;
    else if (ct->app) tag = ct->app->tag;
    if (ct->app) name = ct->app->name;

    char s[strlen(tag)+strlen(name)+10];
    snprintf(s, len, "%s.object(%s)", name, tag);
    return_auto s;
}
```

Obviously, for now we need to explode that in caller's body (probably via macro to feel all caveats) or do `asprintf/malloc` in callee and `free` in caller.

Comment: Really , just do `int a[compute_n()];` inside the caller. If you find the `sizeof` calculation ugly then define a macro.

Comment: How would `int *a = callee(); int *b = callee();` work?

Comment: @KerrekSB like `int a[compute_n1()]; int b[compute_n2()];` do

Comment: @user3125367: OK, but what's the codegen for that? Remember that you should be able to compile functions in isolation and link them later.

Comment: Wow, we've been using dynamic memory allocation for over 50 years, how could all the programming language theorists have missed this obvious solution? :)

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure about that. You say "this technique" as though this idea made sense; I'm calling this sense into question.

Comment: @KerrekSB I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure I can implement that in assembler (not in C though). Given that, it *is* possible.

Comment: Notice that your A and B are not really equivalent. In A, `callee` knows the size of the array. If B is supposed to be analogous, why do you need to calculate the size? `callee` can just assume that it's `[10]`.

Comment: @Barmar Correct. The goal is to join A's flexibilty with B's cheapness (in both runtime and keystrokes).

Comment: `int a[SIZE]; callee(a, SIZE);`

Comment: @Barmar Added *simple* example, regular pattern in my code now.

Comment: @Barmar >Wow. Seriously, can you please explain why this potential solution is bad? (Not in sense of "this can be done with malloc or implemented in-place" — I understand that.)

Comment: Someone else already posted an answer.

Comment: The basic problem is that once a function allocates an array like this, you can't unwind the stack from there for the entire rest of the program. It essentially violates the whole idea of using a stack for temporaries, because now the stack frame becomes permanent.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that it turns the stack into a heap.

Comment: Please don't vandalize, even your own questions. Questions belong to the community.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry. The fact that I'm contributing for years and *my every* question (I do not ask trivials) is left unanswered or even refused despite correct formulation can drive crazy anyone. I do not see any motivation to be here just to answer another dummy noob's questions.

Comment: @user3125367: That's your prerogative (albeit regrettable), but nonetheless, don't vandalize. :-S Sorry that you've met with less enthusiasm on this question than you were probably expecting, but if it's any consolation, SO isn't personal and it's not a response to you as a person...

Comment: Also, it looks to me like *most* of your questions have at least one answer -- surely it's not all bleak?

Comment: @Barmar The basic problem is that once a function allocates an array not like this, but like `int a[100500]; callee(a)`, you can't unwind the stack from there for the entire rest of the program. Your point is not on solution details (what I'm asking for), but on misuse of stack space available right now. You don't like it, okay, I got that with first wow-look-at-fool comment

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate at another site, like cs.stackexchange.com. SO is for practical programming questions using existing languages, libraries, etc. Not for discussion of computer architectures, the design of programming languages, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a theoretical question, not a practical programming question.

Answer (score 3):

This seems a very bad idea for any non-trivial scenario. Just remember a stack frame contains all the local variables along with return address, saved base pointer, and so on. In your model, a caller would need to "inherit" the whole frame as part of its own frame. Then think about you might pass this returned value to some OTHER function. So what if this function wants to return more than just an integral value? You would easily end up with a *huge* stack frame for `main()`. Any heap implementation is probably more space efficient.